# Facebook follow button does not display error message?

Tags: facebook

I'm using this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button and it's working fine. But what if I enter a facebook url that doesn't exist? It doesn't display any error message and just disappears. I want to display an error message when the user enters a wrong URL. Following is my code:

```
function wpfollow_func() {
var checkURL = jQuery("#profileCheck").hasClass("has-error");

if (!checkURL) {
    var faces = jQuery('#facey').is(':checked');
    var layout = jQuery('input[name=layout]:checked').val();

    var url = jQuery('#profile').val();
    if (url == '' || url == null) {
        url = 'https://www.facebook.com/zuck';
    }

    var token = url.indexOf('http://');
    if (token == -1) {
        token = url.indexOf('https://');
    }
    if (token == -1) {
        url = 'http://' + url;
    }
    var data = '<div class="fb-follow" data-href="' + url + '" data-layout="' + layout + '" data-show-faces="' + faces + '"></div>';

    console.log(data);
    jQuery('.fb-button').html(data);

    FB.XFBML.parse();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this is intended and there is no way you can use JS to check yourself because the button will load inside an iFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('some_element'), function() {
alert('I rendered');
});
```

Following url may help you:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse